# GKE AutoPilot does not automatically scale my nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running multiple pods via `kubectl run` like `kubectl run pod-0 --limits="cpu=250m" --restart=Never --image=example/image:latest` where I have 5 clusters with each region: HK, India, Korea, Indonesia and  Taiwan.

I run 12 pods with `limits=cpu=250m`. In India and Hong Kong it is fine where all my pods are being served by 6 nodes. However in Taiwan, Indoensia and Korea.. They just have 3 nodes and 9 of my pods are continuously on a pending state for almost an hour. Seems like I can scale the nodes manually, so what can I do here? Take note that my pods are simply just running a script with stateless process

Comment: Could you provide a description, based on which, this behaviour can be reproduced on a test cluster ?

Comment: It is quota I just found out yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, and it could be related to quotas. Check if you have maxed out on CPU and IP addresses.

I am awaiting quota increase to verify if that solves my problem.